# GetCallbackChannel(Of T) referenced object has a value of nothing

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I'm working on a WCF client that is using two callback methods to inform the client of progress.  The first callback method works fine, however; when I attempt to raise the second callback method I get the error "referenced object has a value of nothing".  This happens on the line of code in this read only property:

```
Private ReadOnly Property Callback() As IBulkFilingCallback
    Get
        Return OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel(Of IBulkFilingCallback)()
    End Get
End Property
```

Both times that I do the callback, I use this property to get the call back instance but with different callback methods.

Answer (score 0):

Had to create a member to store the instance instead of trying to create one twice:

```
Private _callback As IBulkFilingCallback

Private ReadOnly Property Callback() As IBulkFilingCallback
    Get
        If _callback Is Nothing Then
            _callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel(Of IBulkFilingCallback)()
        End If
        Return _callback
    End Get
End Property
```